# illegal character 'X' at offset 37

Tags: php, xml, curl, illegal-characters

I am using xml with cURL to contact Canada post and 
get shipping labels.

This is the  code I use.

**The platform is ExpressionEngine**

```
<?php
 /**
 * Sample code for the CreateShipment Canada Post service.
 * 
 * The CreateShipment service is used to create a new shipping item, to 
 * request the generation of a softcopy image of shipping labels, and to provide 
 * links to these shipping labels and other information associated with the 
 * shipping item.. 
 *
 * This sample is configured to access the Developer Program sandbox environment. 
 * Use your development key username and password for the web service credentials.
 * 
 **/

// Your username, password and customer number are imported from the following file     
// CPCWS_Shipping_PHP_Samples\REST\shipping\user.ini
$userProperties = parse_ini_file(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) . '/../user.ini');

$username = $userProperties['username']; 
$password = $userProperties['password'];
$mailedBy = $userProperties['customerNumber'];
$mobo = $userProperties['customerNumber'];

// REST URL
$service_url = 'https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/' . $mailedBy . '/' . $mobo . '/shipment';

// Create CreateShipment request xml
$groupId = '4326432';
$requestedShippingPoint = 'H2B1A0';
$mailingDate = '2012-10-24';
$contractId = '0040662521';

$xmlRequest = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shipment xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/shipment">
    <group-id>{$groupId}</group-id>
    <requested-shipping-point>{$requestedShippingPoint}</requested-shipping-point>
    <expected-mailing-date>{$mailingDate}</expected-mailing-date>
    <delivery-spec>
        <service-code>DOM.EP</service-code>
            <sender>
                <name>Bulma</name>
                <company>Capsule Corp.</company>
                <contact-phone>1 (514) 820 5879</contact-phone>
                <address-details>
                    <address-line-1>502 MAIN ST N</address-line-1>
                    <city>MONTREAL</city>
                    <prov-state>QC</prov-state>
                    <country-code>CA</country-code>
                    <postal-zip-code>H2B1A0</postal-zip-code>
                </address-details>
            </sender>
            <destination>
                <name>Ryuko Saito</name>
                <company>Kubere</company>
                <address-details>
                    <address-line-1>23 jardin private</address-line-1>
                    <city>Ottawa</city>
                    <prov-state>ON</prov-state>
                    <country-code>CA</country-code>
                    <postal-zip-code>K1K4T3</postal-zip-code>
                </address-details>
            </destination>
        <options>
            <option>
                <option-code>DC</option-code>
            </option>
        </options>
        <parcel-characteristics>
            <weight>15</weight>
            <dimensions>
                <length>6</length>
                <width>12</width>
                <height>9</height>
            </dimensions>
            <unpackaged>true</unpackaged>
            <mailing-tube>false</mailing-tube>
        </parcel-characteristics>
        <notification>
            <email>ryuko.saito@kubere.com</email>
            <on-shipment>true</on-shipment>
            <on-exception>false</on-exception>
            <on-delivery>true</on-delivery>
        </notification>
        <print-preferences>
            <output-format>8.5x11</output-format>
        </print-preferences>
        <preferences>
            <show-packing-instructions>true</show-packing-instructions>
            <show-postage-rate>false</show-postage-rate>
            <show-insured-value>true</show-insured-value>
        </preferences>
        <settlement-info>
            <contract-id>{$contractId}</contract-id>
            <intended-method-of-payment>Account</intended-method-of-payment>
        </settlement-info>
    </delivery-spec>
</shipment>
XML;

$curl = curl_init($service_url); // Create REST Request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath(dirname($argv[0])) . '/../../../third-party/cert/cacert.pem'); // Signer Certificate in PEM format
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v2+xml', 'Accept: application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v2+xml'));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl); // Execute REST Request
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl) . "\n";
}

echo 'HTTP Response Status: ' . curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "\n";

curl_close($curl);

// Example of using SimpleXML to parse xml response
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>' . preg_replace('/<\?xml.*\?>/','',$curl_response) . '</root>');
if (!$xml) {
    echo 'Failed loading XML' . "\n";
    echo $curl_response . "\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t" . $error->message;
    }
} else {
    if ($xml->{'shipment-info'} ) {
        $shipment = $xml->{'shipment-info'}->children('http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/shipment');
        if ( $shipment->{'shipment-id'} ) {
            echo  'Shipment Id: ' . $shipment->{'shipment-id'} . "\n";                 
            foreach ( $shipment->{'links'}->{'link'} as $link ) {  
                echo $link->attributes()->{'rel'} . ': ' . $link->attributes()->{'href'} . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($xml->{'messages'} ) {                  
        $messages = $xml->{'messages'}->children('http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/messages');       
        foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
            echo 'Error Code: ' . $message->code . "\n";
            echo 'Error Msg: ' . $message->description . "\n\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**I received error below**

HTTP Response Status: 500 Error Code: Server Error Msg: illegal character 'X' at offset 37 of /rs/0000000000/0000000000/shipment

(I changed customer number to "0000000000")

Can someone explain what is the meaning of above message?

Thank you very much

Comment: An HTTP Response Status of 500 generally means Internal Server Error (something is messed up server side).
Additionally, I looked into Canada Posts error messages:
http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/messagescodetables.jsf
And there's no "500" code. Perhaps something in your CURL is causing an edge-case error on their end.

Comment: what is output if you run `mb_detect_encoding` on your `$xmlRequest`? (Perhaps you're sending malformed UTF8)

Comment: Dear Shad,  thank you very much for your reply.  When I run mb_detect_encoding  I got "ASCII Error" message.  Please guide me to solve this issue.  Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention I use the above code on ExpressionEngine

Comment: Dear Shad,  Yes as you stated  "An HTTP Response Status of 500 generally means Internal Server Error (something is messed up server side)" is correct.  I test the same code in MAMP server.  I could get labels within 5 minutes.  Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 0):

The provider is probably (like *all* "enterprise" providers) not using a proper XML parser. Try putting a space before the closing characters of the PI, or failing that remove the PI entirely.

Comment: Dear Ignacio vazquez-Abrams,  What do you mean by "closing characters of the PI" Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: The `?>` at the end of the processing instruction.

Answer (score 0):

37 characters puts you right at the end of the XML Prolog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Either the host does not handle this or you have may have a DOS/UNIX End-of-Line issue.

First, try removing the XML Prolog and see if that helps.

If that doesn't help, then (depending on your editor) save the PHP source as a UNIX file to get the end of line markers right. If that doesn't work, try saving it as a DOS file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try your recomendations